# Context dependent injections in various DI frameworks

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac, structuremap, simple-injector

**The circumstances**

We have recently begun looking for a replacement for NInject. We looked at Simple-Injector, AutoFac and StructureMap. But in our tests we couldn't reproduce a binding that was possible in NIinject, but not in the other frameworks.

**The problem**

Let's assume we have the following interfaces which are commonly used trough multiple applications:

```
public interface IRepository {...}

public interface ILog {...}
```

with a default implementation for `IRepository`:

```
public class DefaultRepository : IRepository {
    public DefaultRepository(ILog logger) {...}
}
```

and two implementations for `ILog` - one `DefaultLogger` and the other `SimpleLogger`.

And two classes that consume the `IRepository`:

```
public class Crypter {
    public Crypter(IRepository repository) {...}
}

public class OtherService {
    public OtherService(IRepository repository) {...}
}
```

What we want to achieve is the following:

- Bind `ILog` to `SimpleLogger` when it is injected into `Crypter` or **any other class injected into it**. In out example the `SimpleLogger` would be injected into `DefaultRepository` which is injected into `Crypter`
- Bind `ILog` to `DefaultLogger` for all other bindings. In our example the `DefaultLogger` would be injected into `DefaultRepository` which is injected into `OtherService`

This is due to the `Crypter` class (and any services it uses) must be logged to a special place. But I could imagine similar scenarios where this could be applicable (solving circular dependencies for example).

**The question(s)**

- Why is this not possible in the other DI frameworks? If it is (with bindings or otherwise), please supply an example.
- Is this not a common injection scenario?

Comment: After some additional insight I see how this question is basically 2 completelly seperate questions merged into one - and the second essentialy asking for opinions. I don't see, however, how I could reform the question to comply with the requirements, so I'll just leave it as is. Might be still useful to someone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is this not possible in the other DI frameworks?

I can't speak for other DI Containers, but Context Based injection is supported by Simple Injector. Just take a look at the [Context based injection in the documentation](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection).

Besides this, there are numerous Stackoverflow questions about this such as:

- [Ninject WhenInjectedInto equivalent in Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305386/ninject-wheninjectedinto-equivalent-in-simple-injector)
- [Simple Injector conditional injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27750322/simple-injector-conditional-injection)
- [ContextDependent instance as Singleton in Simple Injector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114978/contextdependent-instance-as-singleton-in-simple-injector)

> Is this not a usual injection scenario?

That depends. The Simple Injector documentation [states](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#context-based-injection):

> **In many cases context based injection is not the best solution, and the design should be reevaluated. In some narrow cases however it can make sense.**

A common misuse of context based injection is to work around [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) violations.